# How to deploy a software in python on windows

Tags: python, windows

I have developed some simple project using python.
In this project I have created a simple gui using pygtk. GUI is used to control the Arduino board i.e., to control the webcam rotation.

Now I want to make this application as a complete installation software. i.e., I want to create on setup.exe file which installs the software.

In general I want to convert an application developed in python as a complete installable software.

Also In development , If I use some third party packages like "lxml" or "VedioCapture" , How to handle these type of dependencies while generating installable software?

Answer (score 1):

Check py2exe to create an executable out of your python code.

To make an installer, check innosetup.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

http://www.py2exe.org/